# App Elements not rendering/inspect in IOS using appium and Xcui Automation testing

Tags: automated-testing, appium, uiautomation, ios

[image]Currently working in a automation project. Element tag was not rendered. though i check some random element, I'm getting the message of element is not intractable. But in Ipad I can see the input text boxes and grid. This app was developed in micro strategy.

I gave a try in Katalon record and playback to capture the element. But there also I didn't find any elements for inputs

***specifications:***

1. Appium
2. xcode 12+ Beta version
3. IOS version 14.0

Answer (score -1):

A proper description of the error would be great. However, I believe that I faced a similar issue recently with an iOS simulator. So after hitting cmd+shift+k button the keyboard then appeared on the screen of the simulator and only then I was able to interact with the text box.

Comment: Let me try and i will update the screenshot shortly

Comment: I have tried Cmd+shift+k but nothing happened